# semantic-ui-vue sidebar height not fit to screen

Tags: css, vue.js, semantic-ui

I'm using  [semantic-ui-vue](https://semantic-ui-vue.github.io/#/modules/sidebar) 
for a project.But there is problem in sidebar height.. here is my code.. how to set sidebar height for screen size.

```js
<sui-sidebar-pushable class="ui attached segmant" > 
    <sui-sidebar animation="overlay" class="inverted" :visible="visible" >
      <a class="item">1</a>
      <a class="item">2</a>
      <a class="item">3</a>
    </sui-sidebar>
    <sui-sidebar-pusher :dimmed="visible" @click="visible = false">
      <div class="ui container">
        <div>
          <button class="ui button" @click.stop="visible = true">Menu</button>
        </div>
        <!-- site content -->
        Content Goes here <br>  
      </div>
    </sui-sidebar-pusher>
  </sui-sidebar-pushable>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrnzx.png)